# Are enjoying or have enjoyed

Tags: present-perfect

What is the difference between I hope you are enjoying your vacation
and you have enjoyed your vacation.

I think have enjoyed can mean that the vacation  has just finished but is there another difference between these two.
What expression is the most used

Answer (score 1):

You're completely right. "Have enjoyed" means that the vacation is over (and you enjoyed it while it was happening); "are enjoying" means that you are in the middle of it (and enjoying it right now).

I think people would be more likely to say "I hope that you enjoyed your vacation" rather than "have enjoyed". But with "enjoyed" vs "are enjoying", neither is better. It just depends on when the vacation is. "I hope that you enjoyed your vacation (last week)" vs "I hope that you are enjoying your vacation (right now, I am literally texting you while you are on vacation)".